# Weird Responsive issue in Visual Composer

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on this site on wordpress. Overall the design works well while viewed in mobile phones, But the header image doesn't resize along with the text which is over it.

"http://bodyinbalancenewyork.com/"

Is it caused because of css media queries? Help!

Comment: You should post the related code with your question so that it helps other people.

Answer (score 0):

Below style is applied to the header image,

```
.vc_custom_1457453060838 {
    margin-top: -60px !important;
    border-bottom-width: 15px !important;
    padding-top: 200px !important;
    padding-right: 150px !important;
    padding-bottom: 150px !important;
    padding-left: 150px !important;
    background-image: url(http://bodyinbalancenewyork.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/nyc-chiropractor.jpg?id=969) !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
    border-bottom-color: #020202 !important;
    border-bottom-style: solid !important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
}
```

The problem is that using Javscript styles are being applied to the header and bootstrap is not used inside the header. That is why it is not responsive on the mobile phones.

Comment: Could you please let me know where to add these to make it responsive on the mobile phones? Thanks.